# How to implement a lightweight, non-modal, resizable and minimise-able popup

Tags: jquery-ui, popup, non-modal

I want to have a pagein which I want to display a popup that is resizeable and minimise-able to a small button displayed in the topleft corner. When the button is clicked I want it to return to its previous size.

The content will just contain some text.

How can I do this? Should I use jqueryUi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jqueryUI Dialog Widget to acommplish this.

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="hidden" id="placeholder">Expand</p>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Simple Dialog">
    <p> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
This is your basic dialog!</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(function () {
     $("#dialog-message").dialog({
         modal: false,
         buttons: {
             Ok: function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                 $("#placeholder").removeClass('hidden');
             },
             autoOpen: true
         }
     });
     $("#placeholder")
         .button()
         .click(function (event) {
         $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
         $("#placeholder").addClass('hidden');
     });
 });
```

[JSFiddle Of Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/JonTurlington/7d43c0dg/2/)

Please check the documentation at [JQuery UI Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)